# How should we deal with the [snapshot] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, tag-wiki

I stumbled upon the [snapshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snapshot) tag, which has no wiki description and appears to be used in wildly different acceptions:

1. taking a screenshot
2. DBMS backup
3. Maven SNAPSHOT
4. File system/LVM/ZFS/Virtualization snapshot

These are what I could gather by skimming through the first 100 questions, there might be others.

My opinion is that we should split this tag into more specific ones, like [filesystem-snapshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/filesystem-snapshot), [database-snapshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/database-snapshot) and [screen-snapshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/screen-snapshot) as a synonym of [screenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/screenshot). Another possibility is keeping [snapshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snapshot) for backups &co., retagging screenshot questions as [screenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/screenshot) and getting rid of the tag on Maven questions.

What should we do?

Comment: If [snapshot] is not renamed and kept for backups and co. this problem will eventually resurface, even if we (=the community) clean it up now, I think.

Comment: don't forget about `printscreen`

Comment: Also applies to Android emulator snapshots.

Comment: Is "database-snapshot" not already two tags? That seems like a complete misuse of tags. A single tag, by itself, would always be ambiguous. If it's a database question, it would already be tagged with "database" so adding that to the snapshot tag would add redundancy. Right? Making a tag too specific makes it too hard for people to find what they're looking for. Searching on the tags "database" and "snapshot" is much easier to figure out than "database" and "database-snapshot." Isn't it?

Comment: @lilbyrdie certainly there is more than one solution, still the main point of the question does not change: the tag is used with very different and unrelated meanings.

Comment: What's wrong with that? Unless a question is tagged with just "snapshot" it should have other tags to clear up any confusion about the meaning. A file system snapshot and a database snapshot are just as related as an "android" tagged question about files and another android tagged question about databases. The "dashed" approach is akin to "sub-tags" within a tag and the problem ends up being recursive, doesn't it?

Comment: @lilbyrdie What seems wrong with that to me is that one of the reasons for a tag is that so experts in a field can watch/search for a tag in order to find appropriate questions they might answer. This is proven useless if a tag has several unrelated meanings as a file-system snapshot expert is unlikely to also be an expert with say Maven.

Comment: @Vality So you are arguing to _not_ use dashed tags, otherwise an expert in, say, filesystems, would also have to add any number of dashed-tags to get all the tags on filesystems (such as "filesystem-snapshot"). If someone is an expert in filesystem-snaphots only, then they can search for those two tags together: filesystem and snasphot. Right? IMO, tag terms should be as generic as possible, but when the intersection of those terms is taken, the results should be as specific as possible. Otherwise, tagging gets too hard to perform accurately.

Comment: @lilbyrdie On the contrary, I think the dashed tags are still useful, for one, it is not as easy to place a watch on questions with both of two tags, second, the question should contain the generic tag if it wants to attract a general audience, as well as the specific one to attract experts in that specific field. This also means advanced questions which are unlikely to be useful to those interested in filesystems in general can contain only the specific tag. We want to make it easy for answerers to find good questions, if this makes asking questions slightly harder so be it (IMO).

Answer (score 12):

I agree.

At the bare minimum [snapshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snapshot) should have a tag info and further it should be only for one use case. In this case I'm afraid that it'll still remain too ambiguous even adding the tag info - its too broad and should be replaced by more context specific tags:

1. [database-snapshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/database-snapshot) for database related questions.

   [filesystem-snapshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/filesystem-snapshot) for filesystem related questions.

I don't think [screen-snapshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/screen-snapshot) deserves an alias to [screenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/screenshot), though.

My opinion is that the tag name alone should be specific enough that user doesn't necessarily need to read the tag info.

In short, I suggest we create two new tags above and re-tag the 508 questions currently using [snapshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snapshot).